# get cookie id for payu

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, payumoney

Good day, I am working with Payu api payments. And one of the things I am asked to provide is a "cookie" as you can see below.

[cookie image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8OJZu.png)

How can I get that string? I am using c# mvc asp .NET. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean how to get cookie value already saved i suggest you to use this simple way :

```
string COOKIE_Test = Request.Cookies["Here You Need To Enter The Name Of The Cookie"].value;
```

EXAMPLE :

lets imagin that we have an cookie already saved as name " Test_Cookie "

so if we want to get the value of " Test_Cookie " we use  :

```
    string COOKIE_Test = Request.Cookies["Test_Cookie"].value;
```

i wish this help you brother .